# how remove illegal chars from returned value fo encryption method to use in query string vars

Tags: asp.net, encryption

I am developing a project with Asp.net , and have an encryption method. when i use it to encrypt a string ,it returns a string that contains some chars like '+' and because i use its returned values in my querystring i need to remove these chars

ex :

```
http://localhost/Cpanel/CompanyInfo/Hotels/EditHotel/VKWbk+G9F6E=
```

Error : HTTP Error 404.11 - Not Found
The request filtering module is configured to deny a request that contains a double escape sequence.

```
http://localhost/Cpanel/CompanyInfo/Hotels/EditHotel/bprrmsZ6atI=
```

It works great

this is my encryption method :

```
 public static string EncryptString(string Message)
        {
            string Passphrase = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["CryptographyKey"];

            byte[] Results;
            System.Text.UTF8Encoding UTF8 = new System.Text.UTF8Encoding();

            //Hash the passphrase using MD5            
            MD5CryptoServiceProvider HashProvider = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
            byte[] TDESKey = HashProvider.ComputeHash(UTF8.GetBytes(Passphrase));

            TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider TDESAlgorithm = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider();
            TDESAlgorithm.Key = TDESKey;
            TDESAlgorithm.Mode = CipherMode.ECB;
            TDESAlgorithm.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;

            byte[] DataToEncrypt = UTF8.GetBytes(Message);

            try
            {
                ICryptoTransform Encryptor = TDESAlgorithm.CreateEncryptor();
                Results = Encryptor.TransformFinalBlock(DataToEncrypt, 0, DataToEncrypt.Length);
            }
            finally
            {
                TDESAlgorithm.Clear();
                HashProvider.Clear();
            }

            return HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Convert.ToBase64String(Results));
        }
```

how i can do that ?

Comment: Just a small remark: ECB is not a safe block cipher mode. Here is a very clear example that should immediately make it clear why: [Wikipedia image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation#Electronic_codebook_.28ECB.29). I suggest using CBC mode instead.

Comment: @Darhuuk , thanks , I will check it , do you think it will solve my problem?

Comment: No, the block cipher mode has nothing to do with your problem. That is due to converting the encrypted string to base64 encoding, as noted in the answers below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you prepare query string value, do as :

```
Server.UrlEncode(Variable)
```

and then pass it to query string.

At time of reading query string use method for decode like:

```
Server.UrlDecode("QuerySting");
```

Let me know for any concerns.

Comment: aa any concerns , Let me to test it .i will comment you

Comment: I have changed my q and put the encryption method,check it now please

Comment: Is still facing same error, If yes, post your code for passing querystring to another page.

Comment: @ Pankaj , look at the last line of my ency method,(I use the HtmlEncode). It is necessary to use UrlEncode yet?

Comment: @AliForoughi: Use method Server.UrlEncode instead of that method.

Comment: I used it and steel get the same error : The request filtering module is configured to deny a request that contains a double escape sequence.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6639/discussion-between-ali-foroughi-and-pankaj-tiwari)

Comment: No,I use another option and change last line of my encry method to : return HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode(Results);

Answer (score 1):

It seems your "encryption" is a base64 encoding. Base64 uses only alphanumeric characters, the + character and the equal = character. The equal character does not raise any problems, only the "+" (which is interpreted as a space in URIs). You can simply string.Replace() the + with an _ and vice versa and do this is in your main controller to work this around.

Another approach (which requires no code changes) is to allow double escaping in your web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering allowDoubleEscaping="true"/>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```

This will only work with IIS, not with ASP.NET Development Server. However, this imposes some security concerns. For details, here is a very god article covering this: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExperimentsInWackinessAllowingPercentsAnglebracketsAndOtherNaughtyThingsInTheASPNETIISRequestURL.aspx

Comment: I have changed my q and put the encryption method,check it now please